# EventKit remove event from calendar

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, eventkit

This is the way I am adding all the events in to my calendar, those events are coming from table view. I have a problem with deleting a specific even from the calendar when the row on the table view gets deleted. The code that I am trying seems not to find and identifier in the calendar. Can you please let me know what I am missing here

ADD TO CALENDAR

```
let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()

// 'EKEntityTypeReminder' or 'EKEntityTypeEvent'

eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in

    if (granted) && (error == nil) {
        print("granted \(granted)")
        print("error \(error)")

        let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

        event.title = "Test Title"
        event.startDate = Date()
        event.endDate = Date()
        event.notes = "This is a note"
        event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
        do {
            try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("failed to save event with error : \(error)")
        }
        print("Saved Event")
    }
    else{

        print("failed to save event with error : \(error) or access not granted")
    }
}
```

DELETE FROM CALENDAR

```
func deleteEvent(_ storedEventID: String)
{
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) in
        if (granted) && (error == nil)
        {

            if let calendarEvent_toDelete = self.eventStore.event(withIdentifier: storedEventID){

                //recurring event
                if calendarEvent_toDelete.recurrenceRules?.isEmpty == false
                {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Repeating Event", message:
                        "This is a repeating event.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                    //delete this event only
                    let thisEvent_Action = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete this event", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
                    {
                        (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                        //sometimes doesn't delete anything, sometimes deletes all reccurent events, not just current!!!
                        do{
                            try self.eventStore.remove(calendarEvent_toDelete, span: .thisEvent)
                        } catch let e as NSError{return}

                    }


                    alert.addAction(thisEvent_Action)

                }
                    //not recurring event
                else{
                    //works fine
                    do{
                        try self.eventStore.remove(calendarEvent_toDelete, span: EKSpan.thisEvent)
                    } catch let e as NSError{
                        return
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I am missing in your example is to commit the changes to the event store.

Commit the changes immediately or with a separate commit while bulk processing multiple events.

```
try? self.eventStore.remove(eventToRemove, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
```

Good luck and success.

Comment: I've tried the same but the event isn't deleted from the calendar? any help?

Comment: For me it is working as is. Maybe tom can provide a better solution. I assume, in the meanwhile, even that my answer did not help, he got it work.

Answer (score 1):

first get the event using even Id then delete the event

```
func removeEvent(eventId: String, eventStore: EKEventStore) {
        if let eventToDelete = self.eventStore.event(withIdentifier: eventId){
            do {
                try eventStore.remove(eventToDelete, span: .thisEvent)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("failed to save event with error : \(error)")
            }
            print("removed Event")
        }
    }
```